# Laravel: Formatting data from pivot table in template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pivot, laravel-5.3

In template I want to display product specifications like this:

Model
Brand: Asus
Interface
Interface: PCI Express 3.0
...

I tried adding another loop inside this foreach, but got errors:

```
foreach ($product->specifications as $specification) {
    echo $specification->name . '</br>';
    echo $specification->pivot->attribute . ': ' . $specification->pivot->value . '</br>';
}
```

Currently this outputs:

```
Model
Brand: Asus
Interface
Interface: PCI Express 3.0
Chipset
Chipset Manufacturer: AMD
Chipset
GPU: Radeon RX 470
Chipset
Core Clock: 1270 MHz in OC mode
Memory
Effective Memory Clock: 6600 MHz
Memory
Memory Size: 4GB
Memory
Memory Interface: 256-Bit
Memory
Memory Type: GDDR5
```

I need to display  `$specification->name` only once and then all attributes and values under that type.

This is structure of pivot table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_specification', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('specification_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('specification_id')->references('id')->on('specifications')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('attribute');
        $table->string('value');
    });
}
```

How could I achieve this? Should I change my table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this is with some post database processing.

Take the following code.

```
// Create a new collection
$specifications = new Collection;

// Loop through specifications
foreach($product->specifications as $specification) {
    if (! $specifications->has($specification->name)) {
        // This is the first specification of this name
        $currentSpecs = new Collection;
    } else {
        // Other specifications have been entered
        $currentSpecs = $specifications->get($specification->name);
    }

    // Now we add the current spec to the list and set it on the main collection
    // Using the core name as the key
    $currentSpecs->put($specification->pivot->attribute, $specification->pivot->value);
    $specifications->put($specification->name, $currentSpecs);
}
```

Now in your template you can do the following.

```
foreach($specifications as $name => $attributes) {
    echo $name;
    foreach($attributes as $attribute => $value) {
        echo $attribute .': '. $value;
    }
 }
```

Obviously I've assumed that you don't need any of the ids or actual models, but this could very easily be adapted to work with that. You could also use the `each` method for the `Collection` class.

Anyway, hope this helps.